# Running code through iPython or command window by double clicking

Tags: python

When coding with Python, I've been using Spyder (as it came part of the package that I needed for work)

It comes with an editor, and of course a console, so I write my code and then run it there also.

It looks like this for those who are unfamiliar:
[image: Spyder Screen]

Here I can run my code no problem and get no errors.

Of course, I also save this code to a file, and I would like to get that code running by just double-clicking on the file name. Is that possible?

I can do it now and get a command prompt, but when I do it now I get this error:

[image: Error screen]

(I'm using the same code that's in the images, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is my clear() code in case that matters:

```
def clear():
        os.system(['clear','cls'][os.name =='nt'])
```

Edit:
Here's the last portion of the code, since the pictures are hard to read.
    player = raw_input("What is your name? ")

## The game itself

```
def hangman(player):
    clear()
    print "Hello! \nWelcome to Hangman, %s" % player     
    if init_play() == "quit":
        print "Ok. Goodbye"
        return
    word = word_gen("text")
    word_hidden = ["-" for x in range(0,len(word))]
    av_letters = [chr(x) for x in range(97,123)]
    guessed = []
    turn = 1    
    print ("I am thinking of a word that is %d letters long\n" % len(word))
    print "Here is the board\n"    
    print_board(word_hidden)    
    print "\nHere are your available letters:\n"    
    show_letters(av_letters)
    while turn <= 5:
        if word_hidden.count("-") == 0:
            print "\nYou won!"
            play_again()        
        print "\nGuess %d out of %d\n" % (turn, 5)
        turner = word_hidden.count("-")          
        guess = raw_input("Guess a letter! ")
        als = av_letters.count(guess)
        guess_check(guess, guessed, word, word_hidden, turn, av_letters)
        if als == 0:
            pass        
        elif word_hidden.count(guess) == 0:
           turn+=1
    print ("You lose.\nThe word was %s\n" % word)
    print ""
   play_again()

clear()
hangman(player)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `os.system`, you need to import the `os` module first. The code is missing the `import` statement.

Put the following line at the beginning of the code:

```
import os
```